# Can't create python executable because of stop_words

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, stop-words

I have created a `5_gui.py`, and I tried making an `exe` out of it. The problem is, once I run `pyinstaller --onefile 5_gui.py` (in the correct directory) and attempt to run the `5_gui.exe` I get the following error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last):
    File "5—gei.Py", line 4, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
    File "c:\users\nepheli\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site—packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module 
      exec<bytecode, module. dict )
    File "site—packages\stop_words\__init__.py", line 9, in <module> 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Nepheli\\App Data\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI78482\\stop_words\\stop—words\\languages.json'
[4272] Failed to execute script 5_gui
```

I have imported stop_words in the script, along with many other libraries, so I am having trouble understanding what could possibly be going wrong with the module. I searched up the directories to see where stop_words is located, and it's not really where the error [Errno 2] message says it is.

This is the error and the first lines of the gui. However the gui is a bit massive, so the only substantial inclusion for the specific question is that of the imported libraries:

```
from tkinter import *
import os, re
from collections import Counter
import stop_words
import shutil
```

I also tried several other modules that turn `.py` to `.exe` such as `py2exe`, `NSIS` and http://pytoexe.com/ but I keep getting that same error.

Can someone please help me understand why I get this error?

Comment: Do you have this file - `C:\\Users\\Nepheli\\App Data\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI78482\\stop_words\\stop—words\\languages.json` ?

Comment: no, the stop_words is in the directory `C:\\Users\\Nepheli\\App Data\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32`

Answer (score 0):

Your .exe file is missing the `languages.json` file. It can't run without it.

So you may want to head back to pytoexe.com and retry while uploading both your .py file and your languages.json file on it, and change your code according to what's written on the website.